# What is the equivalent of vb.NET "Interop User Control" on Delphi?

Tags: vb.net, delphi, activex

I'm trying to make an app with event/methods/procedures to be taken from a third party application.
This app needs to be an `active X`.

I have an working example on `VB.NET` and I need to make a the same on Delphi.

The `vb.net` Unit start with:

```
<ComClass(InteropUserControl.ClassId, InteropUserControl.InterfaceId, InteropUserControl.EventsId)> _
Public Class InteropUserControl
```

Is this completely necessary on DELPHI? is this only for register a COM class on Windows?

Also, the function used is:

```
Public Event msgPlugIn(ByRef Msg As String, ByRef MsgResponse As String)
```

And it's called later:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim Response As String = ""
    Msg = "<ID><infoRequest/></ID>"
    RaiseEvent MsgPlugIn(Msg, Response)
    rtb1.Text = Response
    //rtb1 is a regular label
End Sub
```

is this an `Onclick` of a regular Button?

I need to get this done in Delphi, but I try everything, `Automation Object`, `COM Object`..but the third party app doesn't make anything.

NEW INFO:

I made an Active Library and add a COM OBJECT and create a procedure:

```
    unit DataExchange;

    {$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}

    interface

uses
  Windows, ActiveX, Classes, ComObj, TEST_2_TLB, StdVcl, dialogs;

type
  TDataExchange = class(TTypedComObject, IDataExchange)
  protected
    procedure MENSAJE(out DATA: WideString); stdcall;
  end;

implementation

uses ComServ;
    
procedure TDataExchange.MENSAJE(out DATA: WideString);
begin
  showmessage(DATA);
end;

initialization
  TTypedComObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TDataExchange, Class_DataExchange,
    ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
end.
```

I create a Client to read this dll calling it this way:

```
procedure MENSAJE(out DATA: WideString); external 'TEST__2.ocx';

procedure TForm2.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
texto : WideString;
begin
 texto := edt1.Text;
  MENSAJE (texto);
end;
```

Then when I execute the client an error shows up:

`the Procedure entry point` MENSAJE`could not be located in the dynamic library TEST__2.ocx`

It Works if I create this procedure directly on the library unit, Like this:

```
library TEST__2;

uses
  ComServ,dialogs,
  TEST_2_TLB in 'TEST_2_TLB.pas',
  MAINFORM in 'MAINFORM.pas' {SuperActiveFORM: TActiveForm} {SuperActiveFORM: CoClass},
  DataExchange in 'DataExchange.pas' {DataExchange: CoClass};


{$E ocx}

procedure MENSAJE(out DATA: WideString); stdcall;
begin
  showmessage(DATA);
end;

exports
  DllGetClassObject,
  DllCanUnloadNow,
  DllRegisterServer,
  DllUnregisterServer,
  DllInstall,

  Mensaje;



{$R *.TLB}

{$R *.RES}

begin
end.
```

The thing is that if I create the procedure in the unit, I made it writing it. In the COM OBJECT I made it thru the ridl file, adding a method to the interface.

Comment: You are trying to write a com server. Start by following the documentation. Ask a question on any specifics if you get stuck.

Comment: I update with more info/specific Question...thanks for the assistance David

Comment: I don't know how the question was before,  but in its current state it does not deserve down votes, so +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **COM Object** inside of an **ActiveX Library** is the correct approach to expose functionality to outside apps.  Your test client failed because you did not have it load the COM object at all, you tried to access a standalone function, but there really is none.  You have to register your compiled DLL using *regsvr32.exe*, and then a client app can use `CoCreateInstance/Ex()` to instantiate the COM object when needed, call methods on it, and assign event handlers to it.

One of the better COM tutorials for Delphi (and C++Builder) is http://www.techvanguards.com, IMHO.